# What can i do to make my laravel and vue run on the same localhost / domain

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have this project(laravel-vue) that have been trying to setup for days now but to no avail, made alot of research, and yea am a newbie to how the project was setup especially the webpack and web-dev-server setup..
So, here is the issue, i have setup the project which is running on https://localhost:8080 but whenever i try to hit a route, it always hitting https://domain.test, which i got this from the network tab of my chrome
Request URL: https://domain.test
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://localhost:8080/
Have ran out of questions and options, have tried to create a virtual host in the name of the request url which after i did is not showing the page..
is it that the laravel is configured to only run on https or am not even asking the right questions

Answer (score 0):

`npm run build` will compile all your vue.js files and will make a new directory `dist`

it can help you to couple your laravel backend and vue.js frontend

[Run Vue.js and Laravel on the same server (same port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971052/run-vue-js-and-laravel-on-the-same-server-same-port)